# How to store activity log in mongo db from laravel?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, laravel-9, jenssegers-mongodb, spatie-activitylog

I am using [spatie/laravel-activitylog](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/installation-and-setup) to log the activities and [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) connect to a Mongo database. In user Model, the user data is storing into **mysql** and log data need to be stored in **mongodb**. I am getting "**Call to a member function prepare() on null**"

config/activitylog.php

```
`     /*
 * This is the database connection that will be used by the migration and
 * the Activity model shipped with this package. In case it's not set
 * Laravel's database.default will be used instead.
 */
'database_connection' => env('ACTIVITY_LOGGER_DB_CONNECTION'),`
```

database.php

```
`'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => '27017',
        'database' => 'test_log',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'options'  => [
            'database' => 'admin'
        ]
    ],`
```

.env

```
`ACTIVITY_LOGGER_DB_CONNECTION=mongodb`
```

App\Models\User.php

```
`<?php
  namespace App\Models;
 // use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
 use Spatie\Activitylog\LogOptions;
 use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;
 use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

 class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
  {
    use LogsActivity;

 /**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
  protected $fillable = [];
 /**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array<string, string>
 */


/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */


public function getActivitylogOptions(): LogOptions
{
     return LogOptions::defaults();
 }
```

}
`

In user Model, the user data is storing into mysql and log data need to be stored in mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue with the help of this tutorial:: https://nickdevs.wordpress.com/2022/05/17/laravel-laravel-activitylog-inegrate-activity-log-with-mongodb/

The issue was with Spatie-activity-log and Jenssegers MongoDB. Spatie-activity-log uses default Model. We need to overwrite the Spatie Activity Model for Jenssegers MongoDB.

Create Activity.php in **App/Models**. copy the existing code from **Spatie\Activitylog\Models\Activity.php** from *vendor/spatie/laravel-activitylog/src/Models/Activity.php*. Replace the lines listed below.

remove:

```
namespace Spatie\Activitylog\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Activity extends Model implements ActivityContract
```

add:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as MongoDBModel;

class Activity extends MongoDBModel implements ActivityContract
```

Comment: A mere link to an off-site solution is not an acceptable answer on Stack Overflow. Please at least summarize what's behind the link.